# WPF TextBox with popup

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I'm working with WPF Popup. A popup contains some keyboard. 
I want to open a popup when a user clicks on a text box and do not hide a popup while textbox has the focus.
Also I need to hide a popup when a user clicks somewhere away from a popup.
Here's the xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox  x:Name="textBox" GotKeyboardFocus="textBox_GotFocus" MouseDown="textBox_MouseDown" />

        <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="100" Height="100" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}" Placement="Bottom"
        StaysOpen="{Binding ElementName=text,Path=IsKeyboardFocused}">
            <Grid Background="Blue">

            </Grid>
        </Popup>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's the c# code:

```
 private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }

private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

I found that the binding can help:

```
StaysOpen="{Binding ElementName=,Path=IsKeyboardFocused}"
```

But the TextBox never hides. Also if I set StaysOpen="False" the TextBox never shows

Comment: I did not get your question. Why will the TextBox hide when StaysOpen is true or false?

Comment: Your popup never hides because you have not told it to

Comment: Sorry.  Of course I want to hide popup, not the TexBox

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the `LostKeyboardFocus` event and check whether the new focused element is the `TextBox` itself or if it's a child element of the `Popup`:

```
private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}

private void textBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var newFocusedElement = e.NewFocus as DependencyObject;
    //if the focused element is a child of the window, it can't be the child of the popup
    if (newFocusedElement == null || FindParent<Window>(newFocusedElement) != null)
        popup.IsOpen = false;

}

private void popup_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsOpen = e.NewFocus == textBox;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

**Sample XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" GotKeyboardFocus="textBox_GotFocus" LostKeyboardFocus="textBox_LostKeyboardFocus" />

    <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="100" Height="100" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
                   LostKeyboardFocus="popup_LostKeyboardFocus"
                   Placement="Bottom">
        <Grid x:Name="popupRoot" Background="Blue">
            <TextBox Margin="10" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>

    <TextBox />

</StackPanel>
```